# Web crawling specific data using Solr Nutch

Tags: solr, web-scraping, web-crawler, nutch

I saw some search websites like http://homes.mitula.ph/homes/makati and I wonder how they crawl data in other websites like `price`, `image`, and `description` and display it to their site.

I'm thinking of using Solr to index data and Nutch to crawl it. I'm new to web crawling and indexing and so far I can only crawl the content of a web page.

Can Solr Nutch do that kind of crawling? and how?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'SOLR Nutch'. They are separate projects.

You can write HTMLParseFilters in Nutch and implement the extraction logic then configure the indexing filters so that the data gets sent to SOLR.

BTW you might find StormCrawler easier to use and extend. It has a [ParseFilter implementation](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/storm/crawler/parse/filter/XPathFilter.java) which takes XPath expressions for extracting information from webpages.

Of course you can do the same within a HTMLParseFilter in Nutch but it would require writing some code and put it in a custom plugin.